# Inherit XSD namespace prefix

Tags: jaxb, xsd, xml-namespaces

I have a lot XSD which access each other.
Since I'm changing to JAXB I'm currently looking for a straightforward way to add namespaces to the xsds according to their folder structure.

My main issue at the moment is to add the namespace to the XSD itself, to the import in the accessing file and also to the prefix definition in the accessing file.

Here a small example (not quite real live)

```
User.xsd - targetNamespace="common.user"
Message.xsd - targetNamespace="common.message"
Email.xsd - targetNamespace="email" xmlns:user="common.user" xmlns:message="common.message"
            import namespace="common.user" schemaLocation="./common/user.xsd"
            import namespace="common.message" schemaLocation="./common/message.xsd"
```

When I now have a new `Message.xsd` schema I have to duplicate 90% of my xsd header.

I was creating a Namespace.xsd `xmlns:user="common.user" xmlns:message="common.message"` which is then included by Email.xsd. But accessing e.g. `user:name` did not work.

Is there a way to save the namespace-prefix definition in a central XSD-file so I do not have to define them in every single xsd?

Also, is there a way to not need to set the namespace in the import when it is already defines in the imported xsd as targetNamespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* (not 100% sure though) that including into the schema A a schema B which imports another schema C will give you access to C in A.

However you will still need to declare the namespace prefix (like `xmlns:user="common.user"`).

ps. Just a warning - never ever do [chameleon schemas](http://www.kohsuke.org/xmlschema/XMLSchemaDOsAndDONTs.html#avoid_chameleon). It does not seem that you plan to, but i still wanted to warn.